# Add Brackets to a string list

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

Hello stackexchange community!

I have a stringlist with a value and his error for eg:

```
{{"12","1"},{"13","2"}}
```

Now i want to output this as something like this (for a lab-report):

```
{"12(1)","13(2)"}
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to get this working...

Thanks in advance
Cx

Comment: Your first list as pasted does not contain strings, but integers. Could you clarify?

Comment: sorry, i corrected the error now

Comment: now I solved it like this:
    errformat[list_] := 
 Table[StringJoin[ToString[list[[i, 1]]], "(", ToString[list[[i, 2]]],
    ")"], {i, 1, Dimensions[list][[1]]}]

Comment: I would recommend Chris` solution, which is clean&instructive. BTW, try `Length[list]`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Apply`:

```
StringJoin[#1, "(", #2, ")"] & @@@ {{"12", "1"}, {"13", "2"}}
```

> {"12(1)", "13(2)"}

Comment: Cleaner than mine :-)

Answer (score 4):

Or with a pattern:

```
{{"12", "1"}, {"13", "2"}} /. {a_String, b_String} :> StringJoin[a, "(", b, ")"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you intend to do with the output you may also use `StringForm`:

```
StringForm["``(``)", ##] & @@@ {{"12", "1"}, {"13", "2"}}
```

> {12(1),13(2)}

Internally this remains as a `StringForm` expression which may be good or bad given the circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact input/output you could start with this and modifiy it according to your wishes:

```
ToString[#[[1]]] <> "(" <> ToString[#[[2]]] <> ")" & /@ {{12,1}, {13, 2}}
```

> {"12(1)", "13(2)"}

Edit: with all elements as strings, you can dump `ToString`:

```
#[[1]] <> "(" <> #[[2]] <> ")" & /@ {{"12", "1"}, {"13", "2"}}
```